# Como transformar scripts sql em liquibase xml?

Tags: postgresql, xml, liquibase

Olá, tenho todos os scripts da base em postgreSQL e queria transformar em liquibase xml para utilizar no meu servidor. É possível ou terei que converter manualmente os scripts?

Comment: É possível, veja essa pergunta no SO em inglês: [liquibase-xml-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063169/liquibase-xml-generator)

Comment: A ferramenta citada no comentário era o que procurava. OBS. Não consegui interpretar os comandos na resposta, saberia explicar previamente, onde é executada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O programa SQL Power Architect gera liquibase xml, como queria, além oferecer várias outras funcionalidades ligadas a banco de dados. Tais funcionalidades em versão community(free).

Link para download: http://www.bestofbi.com/page/architect_download_os

Como gerar o liquibase xml: http://blog.mgm-tp.com/2010/11/data-modeling-part2/